# avoid longer way to save Excel files

Tags: save, excel-2013

in Excel 2013 when I want to save something I need to go to the file ribbon, and then in the Save As press the C for computer, etc.

Which is the way to set up the simplest way "the old way" to go directly to the traditional Save us dialog?

Comment: F12? This is a SuperUser question. I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 'Save As' to the quick access toolbar. Then you'll have a button. Or just push F12 as Doug Glancy suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can press `ALT`, then `F`, then `A` (releasing each key before pressing the next one) to jump directly to the Save As dialog.

Comment: but how can I JUMP DIRECTLY?